# How to match a column value against a string of any length?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have a table which stores company names and their homepage URLs. Like so:

```
CompanyName | CompanyURL
WalMart       walmart.com
eBay UK       www.ebay.co.uk
Amazon        http://www.amazon.com
```

Sometimes people will submit a URL to my application such as `http://www.ebay.co.uk/amazon`

I want to see if the CompanyURL value is contained within the URL submitted by the user.

I would normally try to do this:

```
SELECT 
 *
FROM
dbo.Company
WHERE CompanyURL LIKE '%www.ebay.co.uk/amazonstore%'
```

Naturally the above won't work because the string is longer than the column value. What I'm really trying to accomplish is:

```
...
WHERE CompanyURL IS CONTAINED SOMEHWERE INSIDE 'www.ebay.co.uk/amazonstore' --- the URL provided by the user
```

Is is possible to do this in SQL Server 2014?

Comment: I'd like to close this question. After looking at all the possible values i have realised its not possible do this in SQL. I would have to do some clever substring manipulation to extract out the domain part of a string before trying to see whether the CompanyURL exists in it or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Declare @YourTable table (CompanyName varchar(50),CompanyURL varchar(50))
Insert Into @YourTable values
('WalMart','walmart.com'),
('eBay UK','ebay.co.uk'),
('Amazon','http://www.amazon.com')

Select * 
 From  @YourTable 
 Where 'www.ebay.co.uk/amazonstore' like '%'+Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(CompanyURL,'//',''),'http:',''),'https:',''),'www','')+'%'
```

Returns

```
CompanyName CompanyURL
eBay UK     ebay.co.uk
```

Now, I would recommend that you normalize your CompanyURL data.

```
Update YourTable set CompanyURL = Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(CompanyURL,'//',''),'http:',''),'https:',''),'www','')
```

So future searches would only be

```
  Select * 
     From  @YourTable 
     Where 'www.ebay.co.uk/amazonstore' like '%'+CompanyURL+'%'
```

Comment: This is the best way forward I agree. Only mod I would do is replace 'www.' instead of just 'www' or else I'll be left with a leading period. voted as answer

Answer (score 1):

You could use [CHARINDEX](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx), which avoids dealing with the messy % symbol (which has a special meaning in a URL).

If you are expecting the input to be a superstring of the CompanyURL in your table (i.e. you want to see if the supplied value contains a CompanyURL), use this:

```
WHERE CHARINDEX(CompanyURL, 'www.ebay.co.uk/amazonstore') != 0
```

If you are expecting the input to be a substring of the CompanyURL in your table (i.e. you want to see if any of your CompanyURL values contains the supplied value), use this:

```
WHERE CHARINDEX('www.ebay.co.uk/amazonstore', CompanyURL) != 0
```

If you need to detect both conditions, you can always use this

```
WHERE CHARINDEX('www.ebay.co.uk/amazonstore', CompanyURL) != 0
OR    CHARINDEX(CompanyURL, 'www.ebay.co.uk/amazonstore') != 0
```

...although you may end up with some false positives depending how strict you are about the input and the values in your table.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work unless the CompanyURL is an exact match for the URL string provided. For example, if the CompanyURL is `http://www.ebay.co.uk` and I submit a URL of `ebay.co.uk` then no match comes back.

Comment: Dude you just reversed the problem.  Oh well.  Amended my answer.

Comment: I just can't get this to work properly. It doesn't return any match when I do this `SELECT * WHERE CHARINDEX('www.ebay.co.uk/amazonstore', 'http://www.ebay.co.uk') != 0
OR    CHARINDEX('http://www.ebay.co.uk', 'www.ebay.co.uk/amazonstore') != 0`

Answer (score 0):

You have the `like` backwards:

```
WHERE 'www.ebay.co.uk/amazonstore' like '%' + CompanyURL + '%'
```

Comment: It doesn't work if the submitted URL is simply "ebay.co.uk"

Comment: @volumeone You are not correct.  'ebay.co.uk' IS INDEED LIKE '%ebay.co.uk%'

Comment: @volumeone I think Gordon knows a thing or two about SQL. Perhaps asking him to explain would serve you better.

Comment: @scsimon I've said it before, and I'll say it again... I'm still not convinced Gordon is human.

Comment: @JohnCappelletti  a bot written by Gates himself. All those books were programmatically authored too 

Comment: @JohnCappelletti I can't be wrong if I tested it. The value in `CompanyURL` is `http://www.ebay.co.uk`. So when I do this `SELECT CompanyName WHERE 'www.ebay.co.uk/amazonstore' like '%' + CompanyURL + '%'` it returns nothing even though the `ebay.co.uk` part is in the `CompanyURL` string. Even if I was to expicity type the value in like such `SELECT CompanyName WHERE 'www.ebay.co.uk/amazonstore' like '%http://www.ebay.co.uk%'` I stil get no match.

Comment: Gordon could you please see how the above situation can be solved? If I do this in my application server then I can use a function called FindNoCase() which would look for a match of StringA inside StringB. I'm trying to something like this in SQL. That is, does the `CompanyURL` exist anywhere inside the user-provided URL

Comment: @volumeone So the CompanyURL is actually HTTP://WWW....     A better sampling would have been more useful.  Am I correct in assuming you may or may not have http, https,www in the CompanyURL?

Comment: @volumeone . . . If the `CompanyURL` starts with `'http:'`, then it doesn't appear in the value you are comparing.  You would seem to have a problem with the data you are storing.  I would suggest that you ask *another* question and be much clearer about what you want to match.  This answers your question "CompanyURL value is contained within the URL submitted by the user", but you seem to have another question.  If you edit this question, you will invalidate this and other answers, which draws downvotes.  That's why I recommend that you ask another question.

Comment: @JohnCappelletti Thats correct. The `CompanyURL` values are not provided by me but are imported from another system hence they are a variety of formats such as beginning with www.. or http:// or https:// etc. I accepted your answer btw because you were correct in that normalisation was the key to making it work.

Comment: @volumeone Trust me, I know.   There are risks when you have to rely on someone else's data.  They will always find a new way to surprise you.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Why not compare like this

```
SELECT *
FROM
dbo.Company
WHERE  'www.ebay.co.uk/amazonstore' LIKE '%'+ CompanyURL +'%'  OR 
        CompanyURL LIKE '%www.ebay.co.uk/amazonstore%'
```